# reading arabic text from a txt file in iphone

Tags: iphone

I am working on app where I need to display arabic text from a text file. I am using following code:

```
NSString *fileContents = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
NSArray *lines = [fileContents componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
NSLog(@"%@",[lines objectAtIndex:0]);
```

I get about 60 records in this array lines. But when I try to print the data it does not print anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the file starts with a newline, the first element in `lines` will be just an empty string. Try printing out the whole array instead, just to verify that your code is working as intended:

```
 NSLog(@"%@", lines);
```

Comment: it prints something like following:

Comment: \U200e\U0628\U0627\U0628 \U0631\U0624\U064a\U0629 \U0627\U0644\U0627\U0646\U0628\U064a\U0627\U0621 \U0648 \U0627\U0644\U0645\U0631\U0633\U0644\U064a\U0646

Comment: but does not print arabic text

Comment: I think `NSLog()` has issues logging international text. That printed text is a bunch of Unicode character sequences that probably represent the Arabic characters you're looking for. If you put one of those lines into a `UILabel` set up with an appropriate font, you *should* see the correct value.

Comment: you were ryt when i displayed character at 1 index, it displayed arabic text. Thanks a lot